# Show convergence for this sequence only by using the definition

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I need to prove convergence for
$(b_n)_{n ∈ ℕ}=\left(\frac{(-1)^nn}{2n+1}\right)_{n∈ℕ}$ and also show the limit.

I may only use the following definition:  $∀ɛ > 0∃n_0∈ℕ∀n≥n_0:|a_n-a|< ɛ$.

So far we've been "guessing" $a$ as the limit (which should be in this case$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$) an then doing $|a_n-a|< ɛ$ for $a_n$ and $a$ as we had both of them.
My problem is, that I'm afraid it won't end well doing it like this. First, because it's an alternating sequence and I'm not even sure if the limit is simply $1/2$ or $+-1/2$ in which case I would be even more clueless on how to do it.
How should I start and how proceed? Do I maybe need to use Triangle inequality?

Comment: The sequence diverges.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence clearly diverges, as already noted. To show this "using the definition", we need to find an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for every $n_0$ there is an $n \ge n_0$ such that $|a_n - a| > \varepsilon$ no matter what $a$ we choose. (Check to see that you understand why.)

I'll split the argument into three cases. Assume $a > 0$ and take $\varepsilon = a$. Then for all odd values of $n$, $a_n < 0$, so $|a_n - a| > a = \varepsilon$. Similarly, if $a < 0$, we can choose even values of $n$.

The only remaining possibility is $a = 0$, but
$$\left|\frac{(-1)^n n}{2n+1} \right| = \frac{n}{2n+2} > \frac{n}{2n+n} = \frac13$$
if $n > 2$. This shows that we can take $\varepsilon = \frac13$ to see that $a$ can't be $0$ either.